# Python traceback to print stack at the end of class

Tags: python

I do have many python classes and which dynamically imports and runs several test scripts (Its like a test automation tool). The logging is also very clear that it reports some error in the correct test script. However, the error is occurred from one of the libraries used by the test script. The error is very common pythonic error - 
     - need more than 0 values to unpack

The library code is too large and the logging doesn't provide any information on which line/statement this error occurred in the library.

I am not able to figure out the buggy line. Where should I print traceback stack?

Is there any way that I can print entire traceback befor termination of the program?

UPDATES :

after adding many debugging statements, the script fails in this function -

```
def _print_pretty_results(self,diff):
    count = 1
    str = ''
    #Calculate Screen Buffer Size
    rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
    for err in diff:
        err_dict = diff[err]
        for key in err_dict:
            exp_val = err_dict[key]["Exp"]
            act_val = err_dict[key]["Act"]
            str += "_"*int(columns)
            str += "\n\nMISMATCH NO. %d\n" % count
            str += "_"*int(columns)
            str += "\n\nAttribute : %s" % key
            str += "\nExpected  : %s" % exp_val
            str += "\nActual    : %s\n" % act_val
            count += 1


    str += "_"*int(columns)+"\n"
    return str
```

Comment: Can you please post some of the code snippet after a  basic investigation? As you said, you know the library class where the error is thrown at, please share that library or code snippet.

Comment: I have added may debugging messages and found the script is failing at the function updated in the question.

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with calculation in buffer size... How do you execute the script? Are you printing all the messages on console or redirecting to the file?

Comment: Don't you get an exception with a stacktrace telling you where the error is?

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni I am running the script with nohup and redirecting the output to some file..  nohup python ../../bin/run_test test_31.py > all.logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guessed it correct - 
Python TypeError : need more than 0 values to unpack is because of the statement

```
rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
```

The issue here is, the above statement will calculate the buffer size and you are not allowing the script to access the screen buffer by redirecting your output to some file and that too running in background using nohup command.

Here is the sample code I have tried --

```
import os
rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
print rows
print columns
```

There are four different way I ran this script -

Output1

```
[root@localhost]# python test.py
44
168
```

Output2

```
[root@localhost]# python test.py > /tmp/out.log
[root@localhost]#

[root@localhost]# cat /tmp/out.log
44
168
```

Output3

```
[root@localhost]# python test.py > /tmp/out.log &
[root@localhost]#

[root@localhost]# cat /tmp/out.log
44
168
```

Output4

```
[root@localhost]# nohup python test.py > /tmp/out.log &
[root@localhost]#

[root@localhost]# cat /tmp/out.log
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is good pointer to workaround. I will handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

How about first using "import traceback;"
then pdb.set_trace() to debug interactively;

```
def _print_pretty_results(self,diff):
    count = 1
    str = ''

    try:
        #Calculate Screen Buffer Size
        rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
        for err in diff:
            err_dict = diff[err]
            for key in err_dict:
                exp_val = err_dict[key]["Exp"]
                act_val = err_dict[key]["Act"]
                str += "_"*int(columns)
                str += "\n\nMISMATCH NO. %d\n" % count
                str += "_"*int(columns)
                str += "\n\nAttribute : %s" % key
                str += "\nExpected  : %s" % exp_val
                str += "\nActual    : %s\n" % act_val
                count += 1


        str += "_"*int(columns)+"\n"
    catch Exception, e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    return str
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also correct, but Abhishek has figured out the correct issue. I upvote your answer.

Comment: I didn't try to solve where the code was wrong, just to answer the questions about 'the issue'; stack trace and where to debug.